# Match wildcard during zypper remove?

Tags: opensuse, package-management, zypper

I'm trying to remove an old kernel from openSUSE. The openSUSE version is Tumbleweed (20191128), and the old kernel is 5.1.16.

The manpage for Zypper is [here](https://en.opensuse.org/SDB:Zypper_manual_%28plain%29). It looks like Zypper supports wildcards (if I am parsing the manpage correctly), but I am not getting the syntax correct. I am not sure how to tell the package manager to match the wildcard during the remove.

How do I tell Zypper to remove packages matching `*5.1.16*`?

---

```
> ls /boot/
boot.readme                  sysctl.conf-5.1.16-1-default
config-5.1.16-1-default      sysctl.conf-5.3.12-1-default
config-5.3.12-1-default      System.map-5.1.16-1-default
grub2                        System.map-5.3.12-1-default
initrd                       vmlinux-5.1.16-1-default.gz
initrd-5.1.16-1-default      vmlinux-5.3.12-1-default.gz
initrd-5.3.12-1-default      vmlinuz
symvers-5.1.16-1-default.gz  vmlinuz-5.1.16-1-default
symvers-5.3.12-1-default.gz  vmlinuz-5.3.12-1-default

> sudo zypper remove *5.1.16*
Loading repository data...
Warning: No repositories defined. Operating only with the installed resolvables. Nothing can be installed.
Reading installed packages...
'*5.1.16*' not found in package names. Trying capabilities.
No provider of '*5.1.16*' found.
Resolving package dependencies...

Nothing to do.

> sudo zypper remove '*5.1.16*'
Loading repository data...
Warning: No repositories defined. Operating only with the installed resolvables. Nothing can be installed.
Reading installed packages...
'*5.1.16*' not found in package names. Trying capabilities.
No provider of '*5.1.16*' found.
Resolving package dependencies...

Nothing to do.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wildcards work only for package names, not for version numbers:

> To update individual packages, specify one or more package names. You
>   can use the * and ?  wildcard characters in the package names to
>   specify multiple packages matching the pattern.

you could however do something like:

```
rpm -qa | grep "5.1.16" | xargs zypper rm
```

Comment: Thanks Chris. Forgive my ignorance... Shouldn't the package name have the version in it? Otherwise, how does the package manager differentiate between different versions of the package?

Comment: yes, your package files contain the version number in their name, but `zypper` doesn't really look at the filename but at the metadata that is inside and chose to match only on the package name (not filename)